# AngularJS: how to change button text onclick rendered using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML + AngularJS code:

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="80%">Task</th>
          <th width="10%">Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in task_list track by $index">
          <td>{{task.title}}</td>
          <td>
            <button ng-click="delete_task($index)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Completed</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

This generate a list of task like in the following image:

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcKN4.jpg)

When I click on the "Complete" button I am sending an http request to server, and that part is working fine. What I am trying to achieve is, when I click on the button the button text should change to 'Please wait'.

How can I achieve this using AngularJS without using jQuery.

Comment: Can you post a sample of how the `task_list` looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. The following code will change the status of button while submitting to `submitting`. Once complete it will change to `completed` and also disable the button.

**Html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in task_list track by $index">
  <td>{{task.title}}</td>
  <td>
    <button ng-disabled="task.disabled" ng-click="delete_task($index)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">{{task.status ? task.status : 'complete'}}</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $scope.delete_task = function(index) {
    var task = $scope.task_list[index];

    task.status = 'submitting';

    $http.get('post.json').then(function(res) {
      task.status = 'completed';
      task.disabled = true;
    });
  };
```

Here is working **[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jgw5qi2wvdYa1NSEI39I?p=preview)**